# extjs: display 2weeks as default

Tags: extjs

I am testing with Extjs demo.
http://ext.ensible.com/deploy/dev/examples/calendar/remote.html

How i can display 2weeks as a default instead of month in that demo?

Thank you.

Comment: You really should accept some answers to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just set the `showMultiWeekView` config option to `true` in your `CalendarPanel`. You could optionally specify the `multiWeekViewCfg` to define how many weeks you want to show, but by default it uses a two week period.

For example:

```
var cp = new Ext.ensible.cal.CalendarPanel({
    //other properties...
    showMultiWeekView: true,
    multiWeekViewCfg: { //not necessary, but included for reference.
        weekCount: 2
    }
});
```

[Take a look at the documentation](http://ext.ensible.com/deploy/dev/docs/) for the `CalendarPanel`.